# How to stack the <fieldset> on top of each other without affecting the panel class of bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to stack the fieldsets on top of each other so that i can call next fieldsets using jquery.
First  fieldset is shown while the other two are hidden.
When i user position:absolute, it will stack on top of each other but the bootstrap panel gets affected and the form goes outside of the panel.
how do i do this such that the panel doesnt get affected.?

```css
#msform fieldset {
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- ===================================== -->
    <!-- MULTI STEP FORM -->


    <form id="msform" class="black-color">
      <!-- fieldsets -->
      <fieldset >

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- MULTI STEP FORM -->
    <!-- ===================================== -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pt84f1ph/)

Comment: Please create a demo of the issue.

Comment: added link to jsfiddle...
i need that form inside the .panel div .. but it just wont happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this, as in stacked?

```css
#msform fieldset {
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
/*#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
*/
#msform fieldset:nth-child(1) {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
#msform fieldset:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
#msform fieldset:nth-child(3) {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- ===================================== -->
    <!-- MULTI STEP FORM -->


    <form id="msform" class="black-color">
      <fieldset >

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- MULTI STEP FORM -->
    <!-- ===================================== -->
  </div>
</div>
```